# Bootstrap-datepicker: Update Method Not Working - a.getUTCDate is not a function

Tags: html, jquery, laravel-8, bootstrap-5

I am using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and having an `input range` for 2 selected dates. I am having problem with the date value that I want to set on the input range. Below is the screen shot for the error that I get.

```
error msg: bootstrap-datepicker.min.js:7  Uncaught TypeError: a.getUTCDate is not a function
```

[image]

Below are the codes:

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit-education', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let add_id = $(this).attr('href');

  $.get(add_id, function(data) {
    let staff_edus = data.staff_edus;

    for (const i in staff_edus) {
      $('input[name="' + i + '"]').val(staff_edus[i]);
      
      //date eg: 01-05-2021
      if (i === 'dt_start') {
        $('input[name="' + i + '"]').datepicker("update", staff_edus[i]);
      }
      
      if (i === 'dt_end') {
        $('input[name="' + i + '"]').datepicker("update", staff_edus[i]);
      }
    }

    $('#edu1').modal('show');
  }, "json")
});
```

**HTML**

```
//Parts of the library
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('/assets/libs/datepicker/datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>

<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker6" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"
   data-date-autoclose="true" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-container='#datepicker6'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dt_start" placeholder="Start Date"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dt_end" placeholder="End Date" />
</div>
```

Need help to know the cause of this issue and to resolve it. Thanks in advance.